# Electric fence energiser on same 12 V battery as 12 V lights

Tags: led

I've currently got two 12 V LED light strips set up to a 12 V battery with switches (battery is recharged with a solar panel and controller). The system all works fine. However, when I add a 12 V electric fence energiser to the same battery, the LED lights pulse ever so lightly (only visible at night) with the same 'cadence' as the electric fence pulses. They pulse even when turned off at the switch, when I believed no current should get through.

Is anyone able to help me first identify what the problem is (is it inrush current?)?

And then secondly let me know how I can stop it from occurring, as I currently need to turn off the electric fence at night (this is at a small off-grid cabin)?

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the power demand.

Two possible sources, either the battery is too small and you need a larger capacity

Or, the cables to the battery are too small causing a significant voltage drop under load ie when the fence unit produces a pulse.

Try larger cables battery to loads or a larger battery.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever touched an electric fence before, you noticed it doesn't have the high voltage on it all the time. Instead it gives a large impulse every second.

This creates an high transient though the wire, and your led strip mounted close to it forms an capacitor between the wires inside the led strip and the wire of the electric fence.

During the spikes, electricity leaks out of the electric fence wire by he parasitic capacitor into the power wires of the led strip, and then find its way via the ground wire to the other potential of the high voltage spike unit.

Most led controller units leave the common wire always connected, and switch the other wires to light up segments, a simple solution would using a relay to make sure all the wires of the led strip are disconnected when it is off.

Another solution is adding a big common mode choke to the wires of the led strip, the impulse is common mode noise as seen from the led strips point of view